# unable to get json response from secure web api

Tags: php, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

In my website, I was hitting a web API to get json data as follows. However, I had to reconfigure some things on the server which I was hitting for the API, and now I cannot receive any data when sending a post request.

When I hit the web API directly from browser, it asks for security certificate and some other security authentication etc.

My guess is that, it's because of the Authorization: Basic I'm using below which now needs to be changed. How can I change this to what works? The username and password I'm using below are correct.

Accesssing the Web API:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
        array(
                'http' => array(
                        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
                )
        )
);
```

Receiving contents in json

```
$responsejson = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$responseobj = json_decode($responsejson);
```

EDIT :

When I just go to the URL directly from the browser, I get the following

> Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
>   information from  (for example, passwords,
>   messages, or credit cards).
>
> You attempted to reach , but the server presented
>   a certificate issued by an entity that is not trusted by your
>   computer's operating system. This may mean that the server has
>   generated its own security credentials, which Chromium cannot rely on
>   for identity information, or an attacker may be trying to intercept
>   your communications.

Also, from the browser, I cannot access this web api using HTTP, I need to use an HTTPS.

Is this sufficient information? Is it because my firewall blocks it maybe?

Comment: Have you try access the api from curl or maybe [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)?

Comment: Can you remove the extra space after "Basic ". What kind of  security is implemented on the server side ?

Comment: @MartinDavidValentinoSiagian , I tried from the browser. Please see my EDIT above.

Comment: @Parthmehta , removing extra space did not help. About the security mechanism, please see my edit above to see my response from browser. How can I see the security mechanism? The web api server is also hosted by me, so is there any specific information you need, or something I can do to turn off this security mechanism so I can access easily

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, since I don't the know how the API works, but maybe you can change from ```http``` to ```https``` ?